# Navigation controller not pushing another view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8, uinavigationcontroller

I have a table view and in the select cell table view I have put the following code to push the controller. The code is below but it's not working here:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    let second: SecondViewController = SecondViewController()
    let navigat = UINavigationController()
    navigat.pushViewController(second, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would never work!

You are creating a new `UINavigationController` object and trying to push your `SecondViewController` into it. Ultimately nothing is getting added to visible view hierarchy i.e. on top of your view controller.

Instead of instantiating a new `UINavigationController` object, try this:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

PS: For better naming convention, I replaced `second` with `secondViewController`

Comment: thank its working but a problem is that i feel some stuck in pushing... Moreover its showing a black screen instead of red which i have given

Comment: This is a different issue the way you are handling view controller. Check the implementation for your destination view controller. What I suggested is a standard way of pushing a new view controller. Beyond that if you are seeing some issues in the pushes VC, it may need more details to troubleshoot it!